# Is there a way to disable #warning in LLVM GCC 4.2 from causing a warning in certain Targets

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc, llvm, llvm-gcc

I'm looking for a compliler flag to disable the GCC `#warning` directive in Debug targets but not release targets. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define NDEBUG for release builds and make the #warning conditional upon that?